# What caused flashing "ERR" after not using Nikon D3000 for several months?

Tags: battery, error, nikon-d3000

I don't use my camera too often. Sometimes it can be a month or two in between use. Yesterday I decided to use my DSLR instead of my phone. When I turned it on, the battery was low and ERR was flashing on the LCD screen. I figured it was because the battery was low and I haven't used the camera in a while. I went ahead and fully charged the battery, turned the camera on again and this time no ERR flashing. Great, right? Well not so fast. I took a shot and the ERR started to flash after taking a picture. Flash popped up and the picture actually came out great. I took a few more shots and the ERR would flash after each time I took a picture. I tried switching out the SD card, used two other batteries and also switched out the 18-55mm lens for a Macro lens. Still, the ERR would flash after each shot. About 15 minutes of messing with it, suddenly the ERR stopped flashing after taking pictures. I was thinking maybe the internal cmos battery was low and it took time for it to charge up from a fully charged battery? Or is something going bad in my camera? Anyone had such experience?

Comment: Reset the camera following the instructions in the manual or online and then take it in for servicing if that doesn't help. <blink>ERR</blink> can mean a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

CMOS battery or supercapacitor charging are likely culprits, as you state. Keep the battery charged to prevent losing date/time and customized settings, as well.